# Задача в новом потоке по таймеру

Tags: c#, wpf, многопоточность

Есть метод который работает в отдельном от GUI потоке - обновляет коллекцию сообщений, которые получает из БД. Метод запускается по таймеру каждые несколько секунд. Что бы GUI не станился пока идет запрос решил вывести метод с помощью Async Await.

Таймер :

```
        System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer ChatTimer { get; set; }
        ChatTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(ResetAsync);
```

Метод который обновляет историю сообщений :

```
     private async void ResetAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetUpd();
    }

    private Task SetUpd()
    {
        return new Task(()=> 
        {
            messangersCollection.Clear();
            DataTable messangers = userDAL.ReturnChat(ClientID, null);

            for (int i = 0; i < messangers.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                messangersCollection.Add(new Messangers()
                {
                    data = messangers.Rows[i][1].ToString().Remove(16),
                    text = messangers.Rows[i][0].ToString(),
                });
            }
        }); 
    }
```

Компилятор не ругается но сообщает что метод будет выполнен синхронно, как вывести его в отдельный поток ?

Comment: А зачем использовать DispatcherTimer  если все равно нужен другой поток?

Comment: @vitidev пробовал Windows.Forms.Timer - на него конструктор WPF ругался. заменил на DispatcherTimer

Comment: System.Timers.Timer же. Сразу отправит в пул потоков. А  у вас сначала идет DispatcherTimer кидает в UI поток из которого вы сразу же уходите в пул через Task.Run

Comment: @vitidev Я не часто сталкивался пока с многопоточной работой)  
System.Timers.Timer использовать и тогда async - await вообще не понадобится ?

Comment: @vitidev `Task` работает с потоком или пулом потоков?

Comment: System.Timers.Timer запланирует каллбэк в пуле потоков, то есть в фоновом (не UI) потоке. От этого отталкивайтесь. Task.Run тоже запускает задачу в пуле потоков.

Comment: @vitidev Спасибо, буду работать в этом направлении

Comment: @Сергей: Я бы не советовал использовать таймеры, async/await превосходит их практически по всем статьям. Особенно — по простоте использования.

Answer (score 3):

```
await SetUpd();
```

Почему именно по таймеру? Жёсткая привязанность ко времени ? 
Можно ведь

```
await Task.Run(async () => 
{ 
    while(true)
    {
       // цикл, выполняющий обновление // 
       await Task.Delay(ms); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Компилятор ругается - после Task не находит Run

Comment: какая версия .net ?

Comment: Версия у меня 4

Comment: @Сергей: А почему такая древняя версия? Под .NET 4.0 разве уже есть async/await? Закопайте стюардессу, обновите версию языка.

Comment: обновите или [смотрите сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42377336/c-sharp-task-run-equivalent-in-net-4-0)

Comment: Такая потому что на XP больше не поставить. Но вы правы - действительно древняя.

Comment: Исключение - `"System.NotSupportedException"` Данный тип `CollectionView` не поддерживает изменения в своем `SourceCollection` из потока, отличного от потока Dispatcher.  Использую `ObservableCollection`

Comment: Используйте диспетчер окна, чтобы обновить коллекцию в потоке графического интерфейса

Comment: "BeginInvoke() "?

Answer (score 2):

Надо или крестик снять, или трусы надеть. Колбэк вашего таймера *уже* выполняется в отдельном от UI потоке. Использовать дополнительно `Task.Run` не нужно.

Отдельное замечание: создани таска != запуск кода в таске. Если у вас .NET 4.0, пользуйтесь [`Task.Factory.StartNew()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd321439(v=vs.110).aspx).